# Confusion about globbing patterns

Tags: path, gruntjs, glob

On the GruntJS site, it has a [section on globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), but there is something I'm a little confused on.

> `foo/**/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/`
>   subdirectory and all of its subdirectories.

I see that the double asterisk matches all paths including the `/` but if a file was in the `foo` path, would that mean that it's trying to match a path called `foo//*.js`?

Before I found that, I was trying something like `foo/{,**}*.js` but that never really did what I wanted and I am a little confused on why that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double asterisk means that the pattern should perform a recursive match; i.e. look through all subdirectories it finds. For example, the pattern will match:

```
1. foo/bar.js
2. foo/baz.js
3. foo/bar/baz.js
4. foo/bar/baz/qux.js
```

It will not match a `foo.txt` file. Although, a pattern such as `foo/**` will match *everything* recursively (`txt`, `js`, `css` etc).

Whereas, a pattern such as `foo/*.js` will only match 1 and 2 because it is not a recursive pattern.

Comment: I understand that part. The part that is confusing to me is that there is a slash after the double asterisk. Is a slash not interpreted as a literal here?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. The pattern that you use is actually transformed into a regex behind the scenes, so the 'magic' `*` is replaced with a character class instead. It wouldn't match `foo//qux.txt` because the extension is wrong.

Comment: Oops, the `.txt` was a typo and should have been `.js`. It has been corrected now.